# Fetching data from Oracle View & loading in QueryTable

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, view, vba

I have created a view with 400+ columns & fetching data from 4 different table (max 15,000 rows) in it. I have specified name of all columns individually.

Ex:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "MAIN"."VIEW_NAME" 
   ("col1", "col2".... ,"col400") 
AS 
SELECT "col1", "col2".... ,"col400" 
FROM tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4 
where col=col1, col=col2, col=col3, col=col4)
```

Fetching data from this View using `SELECT` statement in Excel Macro's QueryTable takes more time. Any input on optimizing macro/tuning the SQL statement performance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the **explain plan** of the underlying query of the view.
2. **Join** the tables properly. Do not do a **cartesian join**.
3. Make sure the tables have the required **constraints**. If you have proper **primary key** and **foreign key** constraints, you could avoid unnecessary table scan on the **child tables**.

For example,

```
SQL> column constraint_name format a20
SQL> column constraint_type format a20
SQL> column table_name format a15
SQL> column r_constraint_name format a20
SQL> SELECT constraint_name,
  2    constraint_type,
  3    table_name,
  4    r_constraint_name
  5  FROM all_constraints
  6  WHERE owner     ='SCOTT'
  7  AND table_name IN ('EMP', 'DEPT')
  8  and constraint_type = 'R';

CONSTRAINT_NAME      CONSTRAINT_TYPE      TABLE_NAME      R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------- -----------------
FK_DEPTNO            R                    EMP             PK_DEPT

SQL>
```

So, we should see the **table scan** only on **EMP** table and not on **DEPT** table:

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT e.empno, d.deptno
  3  FROM emp e, dept d
  4  WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno
  5  /

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |    98 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |    98 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("E"."DEPTNO" IS NOT NULL)

13 rows selected.
```

4. Based on the filter predicate, create the required **indexes**. However, keep in mind the **cardinality estimates** would make a big difference. **Indexes are not always good and full table scans are not always bad.**

For example,

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT e.empno, d.deptno
  3  FROM emp e, dept d
  4  WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno
  5  AND e.empno in (7369, 7699)
  6  /

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2355049923

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |        |     2 |    14 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INLIST ITERATOR             |        |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMP    |     2 |    14 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_EMP |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("E"."DEPTNO" IS NOT NULL)
   3 - access("E"."EMPNO"=7369 OR "E"."EMPNO"=7699)

16 rows selected.
```

Have a look at [How to create and display Explain Plan](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/oracle-explain-plan/).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, I will check EXPLAIN PLAN & share details about it. I dont have direct access to DB, so it will take some for me to execute & check explain plan.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Ok. Good luck!